# How to mock custom UserServiceDetails in SpringSecurity Bean for unit-testing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security

I have `Spring Boot` application with basic auth enabled. `UserServiceDetails` consumed from DB. For the unit-testing purpose, I want to mock it, so the data will be consumed from elsewhere.

How can I do it?

My question is not how to mock `UserServiceDetails` itself but how to mock the way that I can use it to test Controllers with basic auth.

The below is my `SpringSecurity` config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/",
            "/csrf",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final static Integer bCryptEncryptionLevel = 8;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(bCryptEncryptionLevel);
    }

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    // allow default swagger docket
                    .regexMatchers("\\A/v2/api-docs\\Z").permitAll()
                    // require auth for any other swagger docket
                    .regexMatchers("\\A/v2/api-docs?.*\\Z").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

To summarize, how can I mock `UserServiceDetails` into `SpringSecurity` config, so I can unit-test controllers into my `Spring Boot` app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [@Profile](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles),  `UserDetailesService` is an interface creates two implementation of `UserDetailesService`, one for test and another for the rest of the case

```
@Component
@Profile("test")
public class UserDetailesServiceTestImpl implements UserDetailesService{


}

@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class UserDetailesServiceImpl implements UserDetailesService{


}
```

Comment: The question is not how to mock a specific class but rather about how Mock and Inject it into the `Bean`, so I can authenticate to controllers from the tests?

Comment: modified the answer as per your explanation

Comment: It is something I thought of. How can I substitute `UserDetailesServiceTestImpl` into `SpringSecurtiy` when testing? This is the mind-block that I cannot pass.

Comment: exactly that's where the profile will help you based on active profile, which would be test during unit testing

Comment: give the name "customUserDetailsService" to both implementation and spring will itself chose based on active profile

Comment: the only catch is, if the application is already up with non-test implementation, then you can't change it

Comment: This is a bad solution of having testcode in production code. When you say ”test” do you mean automatic unit testing or do you want to do manual testing? If you run your application with a test profile you are only testing your test-profile-code and not the actual production running code.

Comment: Obviously having test code in production is a super bad strategy, unit test are meant to test in standalone or CICD, when I say test profile, it means it will ready all configuration and classes meant for test profile, e.g. database URL, that is supposed to go in test profile, similarly there are some classes meant for different profile, with spring you can play with multiple profile meant for multiple environments or needs

Comment: @ShaileshChandra The answer seemed to be decent and I thought it worked but in fact, it didn't. The reason why, I have hard time to even do an initial invoke of `UserDetailesServiceImpl`. Whenever I run my code and do `@WebMvcTest` or use similar annotations for invoking web-layer, this class cannot be found, indepdendently of it either being in production or in test part of the code...

Comment: ok, btw for your tests aren't you using @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest annotations