# How to enforce MockitoJUnitRunner fail without basic http authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, controller, mockito

I write a `Spring Boot` app and I was able to access and test `Controller` with `MockMvc`. The issue is that during testing security is not enforced and I can access `Controller` with no user.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is it intended behavior?

`ControllerTest` class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @InjectMocks
    private Controller controller;

    private final static String URL = "/test";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(URL))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

My [`SecurityConfig` StackOverflow QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58353403/how-to-mock-custom-userservicedetails-in-springsecurity-bean-for-unit-testing).

Comment: You are running with Mockito, you are creating your won instance of the controller,  how should security be enforced? Instead use an `@WebMvcTest` as explained in the Spirng Boot reference guide. Or if you really want to stick with this, enable security for testing as explained in the Spring Security reference guide. I would however suggest to stick with the `@WebMvcTest`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I still struggle to understand how to enable security with `MockitoJUnitRunner`. Can you point where exactly into Spring Security reference I can find this info?

Comment: [The testing chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup) is quite a give away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples uses a plain unit test to test your controller. In this setup the Controller is created by Mockito (the controller field is annotated with Mockito's @InjectMocks).

Mockito is not aware of Spring, in consequence no Spring Security will be setup in your test.

You need to use the SpringRunner to run your test. This runner is Spring aware and allows you to properly initialize your controller before the test is run.

The test should look something like this (junit5):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private Service serviceMock;

   @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(URL))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

check our the Spring documentation or some tutorials for further information

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html

Comment: This answer is good but the issue is that it doesn't solve my issue. I solidified understanding of the web layer but how to include security part into the test? I use the `spring-security` module.

Comment: then you might have another problem in your configuration:

_By default, tests annotated with @WebMvcTest will also auto-configure Spring Security and MockMvc_  (quoted from [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html))   

Usually you then can use the annotation WithMockUser to simulate an existing authorization for your test. [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/test/context/support/WithMockUser.html)

Comment: you might want to try to use _@SpringBootTest_ instead of _@WebMvcTest_ and add additionally add _@AutoConfigureMockMvc_. This will load your whole application configuration and also configure mockMvc.