# How to make Spring Security work in unit-tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security

I struggle to understand how to test the `Spring Boot` application with the `Spring Security` layer.

I have asked similar questions [How to enforce `Spring Security` with `MockitoJUnit` runner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401388/how-to-enforce-mockitojunitrunner-fail-without-basic-http-authentication) and [How to mock customer user service details in `Spring Security` layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58353403/how-to-mock-custom-userservicedetails-in-springsecurity-bean-for-unit-testing)

1. I have a custom implementation for [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) which take data from the database, so naturally, I want to take it from somewhere else during unit-testing phase
2. I want to test my web-layer to see if `Spring Security` works and if all other use-cases work as well.

How can I achieve both tasks above?

`SecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/",
            "/csrf",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final static Integer bCryptEncryptionLevel = 8;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(bCryptEncryptionLevel);
    }

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    // allow default swagger docket
                    .regexMatchers("\\A/v2/api-docs\\Z").permitAll()
                    // require auth for any other swagger docket
                    .regexMatchers("\\A/v2/api-docs?.*\\Z").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

`CustomUserDetailsService` class:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
@Profile("!test")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;
    private RedisProperties redisProperties;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(RedisProperties redisProperties, StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.redisProperties = redisProperties;
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // Do queries to DB and return user if such user exists
    }
}
```

I also added `CustomUserDetailsServiceTest` class for the unit-testing purpose only into the same package but under `src/test/java`:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
@Profile("test")
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceTest implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        Map<Object, Object> entries = new HashMap<Object, Object>(){{
            put("username", username);
            put("password_hash", "$2a$08$YjMcOsLmbbUB4DYPxqSAxOa3STLjEDovwd2..Uidwp.asyhSi8Y5u");
            put("role", "ADMIN");
        }};
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity(entries);
        return new HiccasoftApiUser(user);
    }
}
```

How can I use custom implementation for `customUserDetailsService` in unit-tests while testing web-layer?